# Same cmd command returns different results for different users

Tags: cmd.exe, privileges

I am typing this same command from two different accounts:

```
query process <process name>.exe /server:<server name>
```

From account A, it returns the list of processes on the server as expected.

From account B, it simply says `No Process exists for <process name>`.

Of course, this means account B does not have permissions to view the processes on this server.

What settings do I need to change so that account B has permissions to view this? (My account is account A and I have administrator privileges to change all accounts.)

Both account A and B are admins, so there must be some specific setting in B preventing it from accessing this information.

Comment: Is this over a network? If so, account B needs also to have permissions over the other computer.

Comment: I see that this is the problem, so I converted my comment to an answer.

Comment: @harrymc Upvoted and accepted.

Comment: @harrymc I thought for sure this was the issue but I came in to work today and found that account B has permissions on the other computer, so this is a separate issue. Do you think I should modify this existing question or create a new question?

Comment: You may use the same post and leave me a message, but you should add full data about the accounts, types and permissions, and about your network, for analyzing the problem.

Comment: @harrymc Thanks, it will take me a bit of time to gather this information. I'm a programmer, not IT, so I don't know how to find this information off-hand that you are requesting. I'll talk to our IT guy to see if I can get this information and if I still can't figure it out, I'll edit question and tag you in a comment so you can see the question was edited. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this is over a network, then account B needs also to have permissions over
the other computer.